# @JsonAnySetter but catch all props, not only dynamic, to map

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I know that I can use @JsonAnySetter to catch dynamic, not mapped field when deserializing json with jackson:

```
data class Student(val name: String) {
    @JsonAnySetter
    val dynamicFields: MutableMap<String, Any?> = mutableMapOf()
}
```

so with such json:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "address": "Wick"
}
```

I will get object will get:

```
student.name == "John"
student.dynamicFields == mapOf("surname" to "Wick")
```

But I want to have in dynamicFields ALL properties, even mapped one.

How can I achieve this?
For example in spring endpoint so rather without access to raw objectMapper. So I want to have part of json strongly mapped but still have also all props in map.
In real case I have nested objects, so I don't want to map everything as `Map<String, Any?>` and traverse this map.

Comment: In case there's a better way to meet your needs, please can you explain why you want _all_ properties to be in dynamicFields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to generate the map of all properties on demand. Jackson can convert any Kotlin object to a Map like this:

```
val map = mapper.convertValue<Map<String, Any?>>(myKotlinObject)
```

For that to work, you'd need to annotate your `dynamicFields` property with `@JsonAnyGetter` as well as `@JsonAnySetter`.

Here's a complete example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.*

data class Student(val name: String) {
    @JsonAnySetter
    @JsonAnyGetter
    private val dynamicFields: MutableMap<String, Any?> = mutableMapOf()
}

val mapper = jsonMapper { addModule(kotlinModule()) }

fun main() {
    val student = mapper.readValue<Student>(
        """{"name":"Alice", "surname":"Smith"}"""
    )
    val allProperties = mapper.convertValue<Map<String, Any?>>(student)
    println(allProperties)
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could use [delegated properties and store all properties in a map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map). There are some tradeoffs, since you lose the ability to set the properties in via the constructor. Here's what that might look like:

```
data class Student(
    @JsonAnySetter
    @JsonAnyGetter
    internal val map: MutableMap<String, Any?> = mutableMapOf()
) {
    val name: String by map

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Student(name='$name', dynamicFields=$map)"
    }
}

val mapper = jsonMapper { addModule(kotlinModule()) }

fun main() {
    val student = mapper.readValue<Student>(
        """{"name":"Alice", "surname":"Smith"}"""
    )
    println(student.map)
    println(student.name)
}
```

Another drawback to that approach is that Jackson won't complain if required properties are missing; you won't find out until you try to access the property and get a `NoSuchElementException`.